# AESManaged returns different encrypted value for same key/iv combination

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I found [this article](http://www.splinter.com.au/c-cryptography-encrypting-a-bunch-of-bytes/) online and implemented a modified version of it.

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] iv)
    {
        var aes = new AesManaged();

        aes.Key = StringToByteArray("abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890");
        aes.IV = StringToByteArray("00010001000000000000000000000000");
        aes.KeySize = 128; 

        var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        var NumberChars = hex.Length;
        var bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];

        for (var i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);

        return bytes;
    }
```

Now the question I have is, here I am providing same IV and Key (obviously just for testing, in production I'm changing the IV each time I encrypt), but it's returning different encrypted bytes each time I encrypt the same input.

I looked up some posts and they said the output is supposed to be same for specific key/iv combination. Am I missing something here?

---

EDIT:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Encryption_returns_same_value_for_same_key_and_iv()
    {
        const string input = "my input";

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(input);

        var result = EncryptionManager.Encrypt(bytes, bytes);
        var result2 = EncryptionManager.Encrypt(bytes, bytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(result, result2);
    }
```

This is how i'm calling the encrypt method

Comment: Can you print `aes.Mode` and `aes.Padding` to the console to see what kind of mode of operation the `AesManaged()` class uses by default? Randomization / Padding might have happened.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/teoqkr

Comment: @ArtjomB. love that ideone thing. i am even more confused now

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt its CBC and PKCS7

Comment: If cipher block chaining mode is used with a constant key and IV, and PKCS#7 is used (which uses deterministic padding for messages of fixed size in this case), then the encryption of the same bytes *must* result in the same ciphertext. No randomization happening here. Show us how you call your `Encrypt()` function.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I updated my post

Comment: Where is the assertion in that test method? It doesn't really test that you keep getting the same results for multiple calls to `Encrypt()` with the same arguments. (Maybe call it three times and and use `SequenceEqual()` as an assertion?) To keep things simple you could also just write a console application and print the resulting byte arrays to the console.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt yah i'm just debugging and watching the value, i started to think if this is some bug with setup, since ideone gives same output. but i've tried it two different laptops

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt i added assert to test so it makes sense

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/TTh7IO . Using this key and IV and that constant input vector, you should always receive this result. Running it multiple times gave me no different results. Resulting ciphertext always should be starting with `AD-EA-00-A0-99.` Edit: `Assert.AreEqual()` may test for pointer equality, make sure you do something like `Asset.IsTrue(result.SequenceEqual(result2));` (with `using System.Linq`)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt wait a sec http://ideone.com/6IiTau this is giving me different results!! and yes I should've used collectionassert

Comment: Because you're encrypting a completly different byte array there (The UTF-32 encoding of `"my input"` vs. the byte array `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. You declared your string but didn't make use of it.). This will of course give you different results if you change the plaintext. Edit: okay, forget that, that's really weird, you're indeed calling this three times with the same arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101820/discussion-between-szaman-and-maximilian-gerhardt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some discussion, the problem was actually part of the code which was not shown here. Indeed, the original code above always gave the same results and the Unit test should have passed (with additionally using `SequenceEqual` on the assertion). However, the `aes.KeySize` was changed in the code (by some colleagues) after setting the key, like this:

```
aes.Key = StringToByteArray("abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890");
aes.IV = StringToByteArray("00010001000000000000000000000000");

aes.KeySize = 128;
```

However, as we found out by outputting the used key after setting the `KeySize` property using

```
Console.WriteLine("Used Key for Encryption: " + BitConverter.ToString(aes.Key));
```

the key **changes to a random key after you modify the `KeySize`**. That's why we kept getting different results. Sample outputs for calling the function **with the same input vector**:

> Used Key for Encryption: C7-35-58-42-3A-2A-79-DE-0D-09-78-20-34-90-1F-EC
>   Ciphertext: E4-AA-A3-3B-01-CF-F0-C1-07-9A-0B-73-3E-70-C9-8A
>
> Used Key for Encryption: 8A-95-E7-26-60-F9-CE-66-BA-A4-DE-D2-FA-70-AC-DE
>   Ciphertext: C5-E7-D3-32-38-21-54-25-86-61-70-CB-94-46-A6-37
>
> Used Key for Encryption: A4-D7-01-8F-35-2B-7F-2D-E6-0A-A9-7F-95-42-71-D6
>   Ciphertext: F1-B2-75-64-D1-90-75-32-0D-CB-D9-AE-11-AE-DB-DD

The problem is solved by first setting the `KeySize` and then setting the `Key` property itself.

Comment: haha just realized i didn't add that keysize=256 part in the original post. thanks again for noticing it